# CoreOS Random Reboot Kernel Panic with Obscure Message - How to debug?

Tags: debugging, coreos, kernel-panic

I'm relatively new to the CoreOS world, we had a server reboot and the messaging in the Journal is extremely vague:

`Sep 18 07:10:27 ip-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.internal kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
-- Reboot --`

I was looking at Memory and CPU on this system using some cloud Monitoring that we use, and CPU and Memory were not increasing and everything looked fine.

So biggest question is, how do I go about figuring out what caused this random reboot?

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this @christian ? I am having similar issues with my installation and has been considering using kdump to debug it. Any idea where to get debuginfo for the kernel?